# Does the sphere $S^3$ nontrivially cover itself?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having a hard time deciding whether or not $S^3$ nontrivially covers itself.  Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: covers are uniquely determined by the induced map on fundamental groups.

Comment: $S^3$ is simply connected. What do you know about covering spaces of a simply connected manifold?

Answer (score 9):

We can use Theorem 1.38 from Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) to help us here. The theorem essentially says that if $X$ is a path-connected,  locally path-connected, and semi-locally simply connected space, then there is a correspondence between the connected covering spaces of $X$ and the conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$.

We can check that $S^3$ satisfies the hypotheses of this theorem. As $\pi_1(S^3)$ is trivial (this should be proven) we can conclude that there are no non-trivial coverings of $S^3$.